# How can I change the flag in my mongoose schema based on the value of other field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I store comments in `mongoose` within the following model:

```
var CommentsSchema = new Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    comment_id: {type: String, required: true},
    text_content: {type: String},
    reportedUsers: {type: [String]},
    deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false}
}
```

I want to introduce a possibility for users to mark a comment as offensive - in that case the comment will be deleted (in my case - the flag `deleted` will be set to `true`).

I want to change this flag when 3 (or more) users mark that comment as offensive.

To avoid a situation when user marks the same comment twice, I want to store his username in the `reportedUsers` array.

My idea is to create an endpoint that takes the `username` and `comment_id` and adds this `username` to the array `reportedUsers`. Also, if the amount of entries in `reportedUsers` is greater than 3 - it should set the `deleted` flag to `true`.

I so far have the following code:

```
commentsRoutes.post('/:commentId/report', function (req, res) {
    var commentId = req.params.commentId;
    var username = req.body.username;

    if (username != undefined) {
        User.findOneAndUpdate(
            {comment_id : commentId },
            {
                $push: {"reportedUsers": username},
            },
            {safe: true, upsert: true, new: true},
            function(err, user) {
                if(err)
                    console.log(err);

                res.json(user);
            }
        );
    }

});
```

But how can I introduce here the change that changes flag `deleted` if number of entries in `reportedUsers` is greater than 3?

Comment: Nothing related to your answer. Take a look at [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) and [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). In your code, you should use one of them, not both. Have a nice day :)

Comment: In the callback, you could check the length of the `reportedUsers` array and update the user as `if (user.reportedUsers.length >= 3) { user.deleted = true; user.save(); }`

Comment: @chridam could you please post a full example code as an answer to my question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the callback, you could check the length of the `reportedUsers` array and update the user as

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "comment_id": commentId },
    { "$push": { "reportedUsers": username } },
    { "upsert": true, "new": true},
    function(err, user) {
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        if (user.reportedUsers.length >= 3) 
            user.deleted = true; 
        user.save(function(err, newUser){
            res.json(newUser);
        });                     
    }
);
```